# Hiding the jeasy ui layout resize option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery EasyUI layout class (http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/layout.php) for a website. Within a layout-div, regions (north, south, west, east and center) can be placed.

I wanted to hide south panel resize icon.

I am using resize: false, it will not reflect.

### My Code is:

```
if(emailMessage.emailType == "2" && emailMessage.emailssource == "1"){
    $('#mail_content').layout('add',{
        region: 'south',
        height: 250,
        title: '<font color="#002256">Hotlist Parsed Information</font>',
        border:true,
        resize:false,
        split: true,
        iconCls:'icon-parinfo'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation you linked in the question](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/layout.php) suggests that the `collapsible` region option can do this, not the `resize` option (indeed, no such option is mentioned):

> collapsible | boolean | Defines if to show collapsible button. | true

So when adding the region you should try to

```
$('#mail_content').layout('add',{
    region: 'south',
    // ...
    collapsible:false
});
```

---

`resize` is shown to be a plugin method, not a valid option. You're supposed to use it like this:

```
$('#mail_content').layout('resize', {/*options*/});
```

Comment: I want to hide the resize icon (<-->) in south panel only.

Comment: @ZoniacSyedIbrahim The documentation makes no mention of a `resize` icon; I assumed you meant `collapsible`. Or perhaps `split:false;`? Could you clarify/provide a demo or [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?